# DevExpress GridColumn max value

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress in my project (WindowsForms c#) and i have GridColumn object in my code. I would like to set something like MaxValue property to set the limit of value for the cells.I would like to block user to be not able to put any higher value than that which will be specified by me. Maybe someone can help me with that?:)

Comment: Be more specific.There are solutions by Devexpress for almost every possible modern framework: Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, HTML5 & Javascript and so on. What exactly are you using? Also define what should happen with rows having value exceeding the maximum? Should they be thrown away or handled in another way? And why do you need it to be done with grid itself, not by setting filter on its datasource?

Comment: I suppose i'm not experienced enough to answer to question "Not be setting filter on datasource". Can You say me something more about this solution?

Comment: It is possible to speak in very general way since you still haven't specified framework/platform you're using with devexpress components. Anyway - you're somehow populating your grid, from database or something like. So why don't look at the problem from this point of view and limit output in sql stored procedure/sql query/anything else you're using to get your data? It's hard to suggest more without seeing any line of your code concerned to this.

Comment: Microsoft visual studio 2010 windows forms c#. I dont know what's more You need to know  about it. And what else i can say that it's not my code. I don't have access to grid view i have just access to object GridColumn.

Comment: If you're using winforms - then I can't imagine how can you have access to GridColumn but lacks access to GridView holding this column. Both of them are on the same form. Even if GridView is inherited from some base class - it should be protected or public (otherwise you will not be able to get its column) - so you should have access to the view.

Comment: Yes sorry, i have access to the GridView:)

Comment: It is very hard to pull out information from you. I've asked a couple of questions in previous comments (concerning desired behaviour, filtering, source of data and way you're populating the grid and so on), you've left them unanswered. Also there is no any line of code you're using. So currently it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that i will try last time to explain.I have a grid which doesn't contain any elements, This grid is used only for adding only new elements. When we are adding element we can set the values for some columns like quantity. I would like to limit the allowed value for this column. What's more You were right i'm derriving from a base class where the GridView is protected same as the columns objects (GridColumn). Thank You for Your patience !

Comment: Now it seems I've got your point. Solution proposed in Hambone's answer should work in this case. Repository item assigned to gridview column having maxvalue set should fit your needs exactly.

Comment: Yes and last thing. I don't have access to designer which is needed in Hambone's solution. I have to do this using only code.

Comment: In fact, designer is not needed there, it only simplifies the thing. All this can be done in code. Visual designer only generates `.designer.cs` files where all the components are created, so you can see it and do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an In-Place Editor Repository.

From your Grid designer, go to the "Repository" menu item, "In Place Editor Repository," and create a new control -- a `SpinEdit` sounds like the right choice based on what you described.

The control default name, in this case will be `repositoryItemSpinEdit1`.

Back on the "Main" menu item, "Columns," select the relevant column(s) and go to the property `ColumnEdit`, select the drop-down and pick "Existing Items," `repositoryItemSpinEdit1`.

Now, within your form code, you can set whatever limits you want on the repository item.  This is a really crude example, but it should serve as an illustration of what can be done:

```
if (userName == "Joe")
    repositoryItemSpinEdit1.MaxValue = 50;
else if (userName = "HamBone")
    repositoryItemSpinEdit1.MaxValue = 500000;
```